# Make a spell checker in php

Tags: php, spell-checking

Actually I want to make a spell checker for a indic language i.e. Punjabi. I have tried making it before. It first explodes the string by a space, checked mysql if the word exists, if yes, echo the word with a space added because explode removes spaces, if not, then it echoes the word with `similar_text()` suggestions. But the problem is that it is to slow and gives the error when there are punctuation marks... I tried to replace the punctuation marks and echo them inside another tag with `strtr()` but the problem is that there is a space after each word because of explode.

Is there any other way to do this other than using pspell or any other extensions because I am gonna use it on a shared hosting.

Or is there any other way to spell check only words in a big string without using `explode()`??

Please Help..

You can ask me for the code I used before for making this if needed...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I kind of feel like this would be better client-side.

Answer (score 4):

Did you check out with [PHP Spell Check](http://www.phpspellcheck.com/)? The usage is very simple:

```
#PHP Source Code
require "phpspellcheck/include.php";

$mySpell = new SpellCheckButton();
$mySpell->InstallationPath = "/phpspellcheck/";
$mySpell->Fields = "ALL";
echo $mySpell->SpellImageButton();

$mySpell = new SpellAsYouType();
$mySpell->InstallationPath = "/phpspellcheck/";
$mySpell->Fields = "ALL";
echo $mySpell->Activate();
```

And you can add your own punjabi dictionaries, which makes your work easier. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: thanks, but i want to make my own as I am using synonyms and antonyms and also some notes on each word...

Comment: @ShahbazSingh & for those who stumble on this in the future - PHP Spell Check allows custom dictionaries, banned words, word suggestions if you use the core class, more documentation on their website. using this is very simple compared to building your own.

Comment: So how do one make a dictionary from scratch for a language which has no dictionary ?

Comment: @JeyKeu Now there are 100s of dictionaries in PHP.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman how can we check the word input from form field? I don't see any word comparison of input word or word suggestions to display in the implementation.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I have posted my question here. Can you please take a look and provide possible solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66898992/phpspellcheck-is-not-returning-suggestion-words

Comment: @VijayRana Will do after my work, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman please don't forget to share your answer once you are available on the question above. TIA